# coverting false results to true if one came true

Tags: pandas, datetime, boolean-operations

I have a boolen series of true and false in a data frame.
what i need is how to covert the rest false results to true in case i found only one true. Thank you .
For example a coulmn
df["Test"]= [false,false,true,false ,true ,false]

I need to get it
df["Test"] = [false,false,true,true,true,true]

Bear in mind that the data frame contains a coulmn for data df["Date"]and coulmn for time df["Time"]

I have tried many buy can figure it out
Thank you

Comment: if df[“Test”].sum()==1:  (new line) df[“Test”] = False

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's the relation of the Boolean col you want to modify and the date/time column?

Comment: For each day ( df .date ). Has 1440 munit and this time . And for each minuit there is a price a movemnt. .. i have a boolen check on this price movement. So i need for each day .. when a true is achived .. this means that rest  boolens should be true .

Answer (score 0):

Use `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.index>df['test'].idxmax(), 'test'] = True
```

EDIT

Because OP's original data is `String`, so convert it to `Boolean` firstly.

```
import ast
df['test'] = df['test'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df.loc[df.index>df['test'].idxmax(), 'test'] = True
```

Comment: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: could you try `df.loc[df.index>df['test'].astype(int).idxmax(), 'test'] = True`?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'False'

Comment: your data is `String`, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert it to boolean.

Comment: thank you , i believe it is Boolean data type , However i applied your code and gave me the below error
ValueError: malformed node or string: True

Comment: i corrected the data type to booleen and applied your second line but the reslute were all true . which isnot the required rsult
df.loc[df.index>df['test'].idxmax(), 'test'] = True
0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4       True
        ... 
2043    True
2044    True
2045    True
2046    True
2047    True
Name: test, Length: 2048, dtype: bool